# Pandas, set_index + groupby rolling

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to get a rolling mean for 2 years on the industry level, for a time-series as follows:

```
    firm industry year roe
    A agri 1992 0.05
    B agri 1992 0.065
    A agri 1993 0.055
    B agri 1993 0.07
    C tech 1992 0.10
    D tech 1992 0.11
    C tech 1993 0.11
    D tech 1993 0.12
```

The result is not as expected

```
df.set_index('year').groupby('industry')['roe'].rolling(window=2).mean()
```

```
industry  year
agri      1992       NaN
          1992    0.0575
          1993    0.0600
          1993    0.0625
tech      1992       NaN
          1992    0.1050
          1993    0.1100
          1993    0.1150
```

for agri 1992 I expect `nan`, because I want a rolling window on **year** within the industry group, not on the **firm**-level (n observations). How do I accomplish this, ideally without formatting year as a datetime object?

**Update**

Pandas is basically ignoring / double counting a duplicate index in the rolling operation to calculate the window. In this case it's two firm-level entries of 1992 within industry agri that already seem to be counted as a window of '2', but in reality this is only one year and should therefore be counted as a window of '1'.

TL;DR
Pandas should make a rolling mean based on a window with the unique count in the index, not a regular count leading in this case to an effective window of 1 year instead of 2.

Answer (score 0):

From your explanation you need window of 3? Please Try.    `df.set_index('year').groupby(['industry'])['roe'].rolling(window=3).mean().to_frame('mean')`

Comment: hi wwnde, no I think you misunderstood my question. I'd like to see the window over all observations within the same industry group in the last 2 years. I tried as well with min_periods=2, but I get the same output. I should not see an average for 1992 at all, because it's the first year. Pandas is assuming that given that there are 2 firms (obs) in 1992 that we have sufficient range for the window of 2. But this is incorrect, because it's only 1 year, not 2.

Comment: Pandas is basically ignoring / double counting a duplicate index in the rolling operation to calculate the window. In this case it's two entries of 1992 within industry agri, for example.